# WebRTC echo issues in Samsung S10, S21Ultra

Tags: android, audio, webrtc, webrtc-android

We have an application which connects patient to doctor, doctor app is built on react, and patient app is build on Android.

I am using **`OPUS`** as audio codec, and **`VP8`** as video Codec in our webRtc based application, but there is an echo issues 100% of the time in Samsung devices S10, S21 Ultra and having Android 11+.

By Echo I mean:

> **Doctor can hear his/her own voice back**.

I have tried following:

```
            WebRtcAudioUtils.setWebRtcBasedAcousticEchoCanceler(true);
            WebRtcAudioUtils.setWebRtcBasedNoiseSuppressor(true);
```

Also, also set the audio manager mode to "MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION"

```
            audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
```

Is ther anything to do with **`SDP manipulation?`** or is this a known bug in Samsung new devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently echo issue is resolved by using the 3 flags below and **"MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION"**

Tested on Samsung S21 Ultra.

```
        WebRtcAudioUtils.setWebRtcBasedAcousticEchoCanceler(true);
        WebRtcAudioUtils.setWebRtcBasedAutomaticGainControl(true);
        WebRtcAudioUtils.setWebRtcBasedNoiseSuppressor(true);


        // Audio Manager
        audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
```